# How to display the emoji and special characters in UIlabel and UItextviews?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitextview, emoji

I am trying to display a string in all sorts of items such as UIlabel,UItextview,Uitextfield etc.....I am trying to do like this in a manner like this

```
NSData *data1 = [title dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
label.text=goodvalue;
```

this is working sometimes for me ,but some times it returns null for the string like this `"Youtube\ud83d\ude27\ud83d\ude2e\ud83d\ude2f\ud83d"`.Can anybody guide me on this?

Comment: https://github.com/diy/NSStringEmojize

Comment: @Zaph yes,instead of the \ud83d i wanted to display it as emoji..

Comment: @Zaph from json service..

Comment: no ..its only what we typed and send to server.thats only returning back..

Comment: This is like pulling teeth, you are providing just a little information at a time. Like what did you type, escaped unicode or emoji? If you want an answer reformat the question with all the information of what you did and the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Emoji characters are in unicode plane 1 and thus require more than 16 bits to represent a code point. Thus two UTF8 representations or one UTF32 representation. Unicode is actually a 21-bit system and for plane 0 characters (basically everything except emoji) 16 bits is sufficient and we get by using 16 bits. Emoji need more than 16 bits.

`"Youtube\ud83d\ude27\ud83d\ude2e\ud83d\ude2f\ud83d"`. is invalid, it is part of a utf16 unicode escaped string, the last `\ud83d` is 1/2 of an emoji character.

Also, inorder to create a **literal string** with the escape character "\" the escape character must be escaped: "\\".

```
NSString *emojiEscaped = @"Youtube\\ud83d\\ude27\\ud83d\\ude2e\\ud83d\\ude2f";
NSData *emojiData = [emojiEscaped dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *emojiString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:emojiData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"emojiString: %@", emojiString);
```

NSLog output:

> emojiString: Youtube

The emoji string can also be expressed in utf32:

```
NSString *string = @"\U0001f627\U0001f62e\U0001f62f";
NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
```

NSLog output:

> string1:

Comment: The string is wrong for two reasons. First is that you need "\" characters in the string so you have to use double back-slash characters, the first escapes the second, for `[dataUsingEncoding:dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`. Second, but non-fatal, is that the last "\ud83d" is 1/2 of an emoji character, non-fatal because it is ignored.

Comment: string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""]; what about this?

Comment: If you receive the string it should already have the "\" in it, it is only when you type in a literal representation that you need to double "\".

Comment: In utf8 (utf8mb4),  is hex `F09F98A7F09F98AEF09F98AF`

Comment: How to attain this in swift?

Comment: Where did you get this codes.
\\ud83d\\ude27\\ud83d\\ude2e\\ud83d\\ude2f

Comment: when I try second method it shows like this 
@"Happy to help you \U0001f627\U0001f62e\U0001f62f\U0001F431"; 

**Happy to help you \^Af627\^Af62e\^Af62f\^AF431**

Comment: See [Unicode Character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F62F).  can be represented in several ways. IN UTF-8 it requires four bytes: 0xf0 0x9f 0x98 0xaf. UTF-16 required two 16-bit words: 0xd83d 0xde2f. The same applies for there first two emoji characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *str = @"Happy to help you \U0001F431";

NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *valueUnicode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSData *dataa = [valueUnicode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *valueEmoj = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataa encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

_lbl.text = valueEmoj;
```

Comment: This worked for me for emoji pasted into xcode string literals