# How to show emoji in uitextview or uiwebview ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, uitextview, emoji

I am working on chatting project.
when i send the emoji from iPhone.
It not showing properly.
I use the following code.

```
CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake (85, 10, 200, textSize.height+20);
UITextView *label = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
label.text=mytext;
[cell addSubview:label];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display the emoji and special characters in UIlabel and UItextviews?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909856/how-to-display-the-emoji-and-special-characters-in-uilabel-and-uitextviews)

Comment: @rohit mahajan: What are you getting mytext ?

Comment: @ niravPatel  I am getting text "\Uf44d"