# How to properly save and display emoji tweets like \udc3b

Tags: php, mysql, api, twitter, utf-8

Working with the Twitter API for the first time , so far other social api's have been a breeze, I make the request and get back statuses that already have the emojis embedded, but for some reason twitter seems to be doing something funky. Here is what im getting:

"New school, new opportunities, new people #ThisIsOU \u26ab\ufe0f\ud83d\udc9b\ud83d\udc3b"

The end goal is to successfully save these tweets in a db and eventually display them in a ios client. Looking for a explanation a 5 year old could understand since I know nothing about encoding.

Answer (score 1):

So as far as I know, these \u... are the proper way to represent emoji's in text. When you render this on an iOS client, it should be printed out correctly (as in, with the emoji's).

See this link: [How to display the emoji and special characters in UIlabel and UItextviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909856/how-to-display-the-emoji-and-special-characters-in-uilabel-and-uitextviews)

Answer (score 0):

For properly storing in MySQL, don't use \uxxxx codes (unicode).  Do use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  Do `SET NAMES utf8mb4` or the equivalent.  In PHP, use the extra parameter in

```
$t = json_encode($s, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way to get rid of the emoji issue

```
NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSData *data = [commentText dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *emojiToUnicode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    [parameters setObject:emojiToUnicode forKey:@"appUserComment"];
```