# emojis shown on webview as question marks?

Tags: ios, database, unicode, utf

I tried to change the database collation to utf8-mb4 and utf16_bin, still did not work with me !! change the table unicode and db unicode

This UTF-8 encoded HTML is rendered correctly in a UIWebView in iOS 10, but only text shown and all emojies shown as ????????????????

I am using this db to post articles and view them on IOS and android apps
[DB photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoeMS.png)

only this emoji  ⚽ shown good! what do I need by a ball!!

Answer (score 0):

Also, inorder to create a literal string with the escape character "\" the escape character must be escaped: "\". See [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909856/how-to-display-the-emoji-and-special-characters-in-uilabel-and-uitextviews) discussing emojis in uitextviews and uilabels.

Comment: what I meant is that the emojies shown as question marks even in the web browser